# Chamar método TextWatcher

Tags: java, android

Boa tarde!
Estou iniciando os estudos em Java e cheguei a este tópico. Como eu chamo o método `insert` do lado da `Activity`, passando o campo `EditText` requerido?

```
public static TextWatcher insert(final EditText editText){
    return new TextWatcher() {
    ...
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int start, int before, int count){
        editText.setText("Qualquer coisa");
```

Comment: Poste o código completo porque está muito confusa essa lógica. Como você esta setando valor ao EditText durante o evento onTextChanged? Veja o loop: o texto mudou chama o evento, o evento muda o texto... Isso não vai funcionar.

Comment: Então Reginaldo, eu peguei o código que postaram aqui com aquela Máscara dinâmica para cpf;cnpf e estou destrinchando aos poucos para entendê-lo:

Do lado da Activity tem os campos abaixo:
   reportar=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtReport);
        password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);

Eu só quero que alterar o campo EditText(password) por exemplo, o campo Label(reportar) receba um Texto ou o próprio campo EditText altere, só para saber que está funcionando, eu não sei como chamá-lo do lado da activity.

Comment: Depois de ter inicializado o objeto assim: reportar=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtReport); você pode atribuir texto a ele assim: reportar.setText("Teste");

Comment: Sim sim, eu estou tentando chamar uma classe externa , dentro de um package que retorna um TextWatcher , como chamá-la dentro da minha activity?

Answer (score 0):

Como seu método esta `static` você vai precisar referênciar a `Activity`

**Exemplo**

```
EditText myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
MyActivity.insert(myEditText);
```

Espero que te ajude!

Answer (score 0):

Na Activity onde reportar é inicializado você pode adicionar o textWatcher ao edit para receber mensagem quando o editText for alterado, desse modo:

```
        reportar=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtReport);        
        reportar.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
         /* insira código que o ocorre quando edit reportar for alterado.
menos mudar o próprio edit reportar. */



        }
    });
```

Comment: Na verdade eu quero pegar o retorno Textwatcher de uma classe externa 
e usar em alguma act

    public static TextWatcher insert(final EditText campo, final TextView texto){
     return new TextWatcher() {

 @Override
              public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                  String mascara= "Setar texto da label";
                  texto.setText(mascara);
              }
Dentro da Activity :
Classe.insert(EditText,TextView), aqui estou passando os parâmetros, em que momento e de que forma eu pego esse retorno e o campo label muda.

Comment: O que você comentou funciona belezinha, mas por exemplo: se eu quiser usar uma classe instanciada dentro da minha activity , aonde o valor do TextView recebe um valor assim que o EditText é alterado, como eu chamaria esse AddTextChangedListener , já que o valor está vindo do outro lado?
Não sei se me expressei bem... :(

Comment: Reginaldo, só mais uma pergunta: nesse trecho quando ele altera o valor do campo EditText para receber o campo formatado com a máscara porque não dá erro:
   isUpdating = true;
                    editText.setText(mascara);
                    editText.setSelection(mascara.length());

Comment: Qual é o erro que você esta recebendo?

Comment: Assim: se eu seto um valor qualquer no EditText em tempo de execução trava, mas nesse caso ele vai inserindo a pontuação e não trava.

Comment: Crie um outro projeto, coloque apenas um edittext e use esse código. Você verá funcionando e deve concluir que o problema não esta aí. Deve estar em outro ponto do código.